# Relational Database in Symfony project

Tags: database, symfony, orm, relational-database

I am currently working on a sport archives type of project in Symfony, where I create players and clubs that are linked together and the composition of that club changes through the years.
For example : in 2005, in X club there were these players, but in 2014 there were those players in the team.
I'm having trouble understanding how I can link those in my database since I am a beginner.

I have created 3 tables in my database : Player, Club and Team.
The Player table is where I store all the information about the player. The Club table is the general information about a club and the Team table was originally the composition of a specific club throughout the years.
The Player table is linked to the Club table by the club name and to the Team table by the playerName.
I am trying to find a way to link the Club table and the Team table. The Team table corresponds to one club and it is where the team changes throughout the years, but I don't know how to link those two tables.

One solution that I have thought of is to delete the Team table and automatically create a table per club. So for example, when I create the club FC Barcelona in my Club table, it automatically creates a table FC Barcelona where I will be able to store the composition of the team by the years. And in that table I can have access to the Player table through the player names that are on the FC Barcelona table.
Is there a way to do that ? Or is there a better way to do the whole thing ?

Comment: I could also create child tables in my database to link the tables. But how can I do this with Symfony 4 ?

Comment: You need to read the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#the-manytoone-onetomany-association Your question is too broad for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

First of all, forget about deleting/creating table in code. It's a bad idea.

Second - if you work with frameworks (like Symfony or  laravel) you need to change your "view"  of databases and all that data storage thing.

In Symfony database is "implementation detail", you don't think in rows, tables relations.  You need to start thinking in objects. Everything here (club player team)  is an object.

Start  here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

look how symfony handles data and databases, there are no rows, no SQL, etc.
and of course, you need to connect the player  with the club

examples of how this  should be done  are  here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Good luck :)